# Send post value to ASP.Net MVC app expecting a List

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I need to send a post value to my MVC controller.
My model for this MVC has the following property.

```
public List<Guid> ReceiverUserIDs { get; set; }
```

I've tried the following formats

```
ReceiverUserIDs=db9dd11a-4fea-4e03-9520-26c9b9c4bc6a,3a9780f4-2860-4af0-a728-0596c52326b3
ReceiverUserIDs[]=db9dd11a-4fea-4e03-9520-26c9b9c4bc6a,3a9780f4-2860-4af0-a728-0596c52326b3
ReceiverUserIDs=["db9dd11a-4fea-4e03-9520-26c9b9c4bc6a","3a9780f4-2860-4af0-a728-0596c52326b3"]
```

I'm not sure what format the controller/model will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only format .NET will get is list of strings. So the third js format seams about right, but the accepting format needs to be a List.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, you're just trying to initialize your list of guids from string values, which would be done like this:

```
ReceiverUserIDs = new List<Guid>
            {
                new Guid("db9dd11a-4fea-4e03-9520-26c9b9c4bc6a"), 
                new Guid("3a9780f4-2860-4af0-a728-0596c52326b3")
            };
```